# Produce Stacked Barchart in Pandas along with checkbutton

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset of nearly 20k rows.The attributes of that dataset are:
       1) Birth Year;
       2) Sex; and
       3) Area Name;
Now I want to create a stacked barchart like below:
[image]

And this is a glimpse of the dataframe:
[image]

how can I achieve this using pandas? or is there any other better way considering the dataset size?

The Dataframe:

```
"Year","SexCd","Sex","StatZoneSort","StatZoneLang","AreaCode","AreaName","Number Of Births"
2015,2,"W",1101,"Zähringerstrasse",11,"Rathaus",2
2015,1,"M",1101,"Zähringerstrasse",11,"Rathaus",2
2015,2,"W",1102,"Zentralbibliothek",11,"Rathaus",1
2015,1,"M",1102,"Zentralbibliothek",11,"Rathaus",3
2015,1,"M",1103,"Grossmünster",11,"Rathaus",6
2015,2,"W",1103,"Grossmünster",11,"Rathaus",4
2015,1,"M",1104,"Oberdorf",11,"Rathaus",2
2015,2,"W",1104,"Oberdorf",11,"Rathaus",1
2015,1,"M",1201,"Central",12,"Hochschulen",3
2015,2,"W",1201,"Central",12,"Hochschulen",1
2015,1,"M",1301,"Schipfe",13,"Lindenhof",4
2015,2,"W",1301,"Schipfe",13,"Lindenhof",1
2015,1,"M",1403,"Selnaustrasse",14,"City",4
2015,2,"W",1403,"Selnaustrasse",14,"City",1
2015,1,"M",2101,"Bahnhof Wollishofen",21,"Wollishofen",3
2015,2,"W",2101,"Bahnhof Wollishofen",21,"Wollishofen",6
2015,1,"M",2102,"Bellariastrasse",21,"Wollishofen",31
2015,2,"W",2102,"Bellariastrasse",21,"Wollishofen",19
2015,1,"M",2103,"Jugendherberge",21,"Wollishofen",7
2015,2,"W",2103,"Jugendherberge",21,"Wollishofen",6
2015,1,"M",2104,"Morgental",21,"Wollishofen",13
2015,2,"W",2104,"Morgental",21,"Wollishofen",12
2015,1,"M",2106,"Waschanstalt",21,"Wollishofen",3
2015,2,"W",2107,"Auf der Egg",21,"Wollishofen",10
2015,1,"M",2107,"Auf der Egg",21,"Wollishofen",8
2015,1,"M",2108,"Neubühl",21,"Wollishofen",14
2015,2,"W",2108,"Neubühl",21,"Wollishofen",22
2015,2,"W",2109,"Entlisberg",21,"Wollishofen",12
2015,1,"M",2109,"Entlisberg",21,"Wollishofen",17
2015,1,"M",2110,"Verenastrasse",21,"Wollishofen",9
2015,2,"W",2110,"Verenastrasse",21,"Wollishofen",8
2015,1,"M",2111,"Seeblickstrasse",21,"Wollishofen",4
2015,2,"W",2111,"Seeblickstrasse",21,"Wollishofen",4
2015,1,"M",2301,"Höckler",23,"Leimbach",15
2015,2,"W",2301,"Höckler",23,"Leimbach",10
2015,2,"W",2302,"Mahrbachweg",23,"Leimbach",16
2015,1,"M",2302,"Mahrbachweg",23,"Leimbach",10
2015,1,"M",2303,"Sihlweidstrasse",23,"Leimbach",18
2015,2,"W",2303,"Sihlweidstrasse",23,"Leimbach",21
2015,1,"M",2401,"Parkring",24,"Enge",10
2015,2,"W",2401,"Parkring",24,"Enge",7
2015,1,"M",2402,"Kongresshaus",24,"Enge",8
2015,2,"W",2402,"Kongresshaus",24,"Enge",4
2015,2,"W",2403,"Belvoir-Park",24,"Enge",10
2015,1,"M",2403,"Belvoir-Park",24,"Enge",15
2015,2,"W",2404,"Museum Rietberg",24,"Enge",29
2015,1,"M",2404,"Museum Rietberg",24,"Enge",22
2015,2,"W",2405,"Rieterplatz",24,"Enge",20
2015,1,"M",2405,"Rieterplatz",24,"Enge",26
2015,2,"W",2406,"Gartenstrasse",24,"Enge",2
2015,2,"W",3101,"Höfliweg",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",31
2015,1,"M",3101,"Höfliweg",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",33
2015,1,"M",3102,"Goldbrunnenplatz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",20
2015,2,"W",3102,"Goldbrunnenplatz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",17
2015,1,"M",3103,"Gotthelfstrasse",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",14
2015,2,"W",3103,"Gotthelfstrasse",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",12
2015,1,"M",3104,"Manesseplatz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",22
2015,2,"W",3104,"Manesseplatz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",27
2015,2,"W",3105,"Binz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",17
2015,1,"M",3105,"Binz",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",21
2015,2,"W",3106,"Saalsporthalle",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",25
2015,1,"M",3106,"Saalsporthalle",31,"Alt-Wiedikon",31
2015,1,"M",3301,"Heuried",33,"Friesenberg",6
2015,2,"W",3301,"Heuried",33,"Friesenberg",13
2015,1,"M",3302,"Gehrenholz",33,"Friesenberg",8
2015,2,"W",3302,"Gehrenholz",33,"Friesenberg",5
2015,1,"M",3303,"Uetliberg",33,"Friesenberg",10
2015,2,"W",3303,"Uetliberg",33,"Friesenberg",6
2015,2,"W",3304,"Strassenverkehrsamt",33,"Friesenberg",8
2015,1,"M",3304,"Strassenverkehrsamt",33,"Friesenberg",9
2015,2,"W",3305,"Albisgüetli",33,"Friesenberg",12
2015,1,"M",3305,"Albisgüetli",33,"Friesenberg",8
2015,1,"M",3306,"Triemli",33,"Friesenberg",5
2015,2,"W",3306,"Triemli",33,"Friesenberg",9
2015,2,"W",3401,"Schaufelbergerstrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",22
2015,1,"M",3401,"Schaufelbergerstrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",23
2015,1,"M",3402,"Friedhof Sihlfeld",34,"Sihlfeld",8
2015,2,"W",3402,"Friedhof Sihlfeld",34,"Sihlfeld",8
2015,1,"M",3403,"Brahmsstrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",18
2015,2,"W",3403,"Brahmsstrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",12
2015,2,"W",3404,"Fritschistrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",19
2015,1,"M",3404,"Fritschistrasse",34,"Sihlfeld",8
2015,1,"M",3405,"Idaplatz",34,"Sihlfeld",23
2015,2,"W",3405,"Idaplatz",34,"Sihlfeld",25
2015,1,"M",3406,"Zwinglihaus",34,"Sihlfeld",23
2015,2,"W",3406,"Zwinglihaus",34,"Sihlfeld",24
2015,2,"W",3407,"Bahnhof Wiedikon",34,"Sihlfeld",23
2015,1,"M",3407,"Bahnhof Wiedikon",34,"Sihlfeld",24
2015,1,"M",3408,"Sihlhölzli",34,"Sihlfeld",21
2015,2,"W",3408,"Sihlhölzli",34,"Sihlfeld",21
2015,1,"M",4101,"Kalkbreite",41,"Werd",11
2015,2,"W",4101,"Kalkbreite",41,"Werd",19
```

Comment: we will need to see the dataframe you are talking about.

Comment: added dataframe.please check.

Comment: Add a *copiable* dataframe: text, not an image

Comment: done.please check.

Comment: @SabidBinHabib, what exactly do want to plot?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you need to take to get the data in the proper format before you can plot it.  First, the data needs to be aggregated according to the `AreaCode` and `Sex` (and possibly by year if you want).  We can call `.groupby` followed by `.sum` on the dataframe to aggregate the data.

However, it still won't be in the form we want.  To make a stacked bar chart, each stack is a column.  So we need a `male` and `female` column.  In other words, we need to pivot the data to split the `sex` column.

Example code:

```
# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv('text.txt')

# aggregate by the columns of interest
agg_df = df.groupby(['AreaCode','Sex']).sum()

# move "AreaCode" and "Sex" out of the index and back to columns
agg_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# pivot the data, setting the AreaCode as the row indices, splitting
# 'Sex' into 'M' and 'W' columns, and using num.births as the values
piv_df = agg_df.pivot(index='AreaCode', columns='Sex', values='Number Of Births')

# plot as a stacked bar
piv_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply..how can I add checkbutton option here so that if male is checked and female is unchecked then only male data will be shown in the barchart and vice varsa?

Comment: That requires using a different package other than matplotlib, which is what pandas is using.  I would recommend looking into bokeh for interactive graphics.